# como guardar el valor (value) de un DropDownList En ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp, vb, dropdownlist

Soy nuevo en ASP.NET y en mi investigacion autodidacta me encontre con un problema:

Tengo un formulario con sus respectivos label y textbox y boton guardar que los insertaba en la base de datos, hasta hay todo bien.

Luego agregue como otra opcion un DropDownList y aunque me sigue guardando el valor que toma del DropDownList es = 0.

No se nada de ASP.NET, estoy partiendo con este lenguaje, me podrian orientar como aprender y como guardar el value del DropDownList, no el texto seleccionado:

CODIGO DE FORMULARIO:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Usuarios.aspx.vb" Inherits="Usuarios" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">
    <style type="text/css">

    .auto-style24 {
        width: 99%;
    }
        .auto-style23 {
        width: 138px;
    }
    .auto-style20 {
        width: 138px;
        height: 51px;
    }
    .auto-style21 {
        width: 579px;
        height: 51px;
    }
    .auto-style22 {
        height: 51px;
    }
        .auto-style10 {
            width: 121px;
            height: 30px;
        }
        .auto-style11 {
            width: 14px;
            height: 30px;
        }
        .auto-style12 {
            width: 166px;
            height: 30px;
        }
        .auto-style13 {
            width: 17px;
            height: 30px;
        }
        .auto-style14 {
            width: 25px;
            height: 30px;
        }
        .auto-style15 {
            width: 21px;
            height: 30px;
        }
        .auto-style16 {
            height: 30px;
        }
        .auto-style19 {
            width: 198px;
            height: 30px;
        }
        .auto-style25 {
            width: 121px;
            height: 29px;
        }
        .auto-style26 {
            width: 14px;
            height: 29px;
        }
        .auto-style27 {
            width: 198px;
            height: 29px;
        }
        .auto-style4 {
            width: 14px;
        }
        .auto-style6 {
            width: 166px;
        }
        .auto-style7 {
            width: 17px;
        }
        .auto-style8 {
            width: 25px;
        }
        .auto-style9 {
            width: 21px;
        }
        </style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
    <table class="auto-style24">
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style23">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="auto-style2" align="center">
                <h2>Agregar Usuario</h2>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style20"></td>
            <td class="auto-style21"></td>
            <td class="auto-style22"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style23">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="auto-style2">
                <table width="100%">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style10">Rut</td>
                            <td class="auto-style11">:</td>
                            <td class="auto-style12">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="rut" runat="server" Width="157px" ErrorMessage="Campo Requerido" ></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <td class="auto-style13"></td>
                            <td class="auto-style14">DV</td>
                            <td class="auto-style15">:</td>
                            <td class="auto-style16">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="dv" runat="server" Width="34px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style10">Nombre Usuario</td>
                            <td class="auto-style11">:</td>
                            <td class="auto-style19" colspan="5">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="nom_usuario" runat="server" Width="340px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style25">Email Usuario</td>
                            <td class="auto-style26">:</td>
                            <td class="auto-style27" colspan="5">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="mail_user" runat="server" Width="339px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style25">Tipo de Usuario</td>
                            <td class="auto-style26">:</td>
                            <td class="auto-style27" colspan="5">
                                <!--<asp:TextBox ID="p_user" runat="server" Width="339px"></asp:TextBox>-->
                                <!--<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="DESC_PERFIL" DataValueField="PERFIL_USUARIO">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationGestion %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [PERFIL_USUARIO], [DESC_PERFIL] FROM [RPT_PERFIL_USUARIO]
"></asp:SqlDataSource>-->
                                   <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="0">Seleccione Tipo...</asp:ListItem>
                                       <asp:ListItem Value="1">Usuario</asp:ListItem>
                                       <asp:ListItem Value="2">Administrador</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style3">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="auto-style4">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="auto-style6">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="auto-style7">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="auto-style8">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="auto-style9">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style3">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="auto-style4">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="auto-style6">
                                <asp:Button ID="Btn_add" runat="server" Height="24px" Text="Agregar" Width="75px" />
                            </td>
                            <td class="auto-style7" colspan="3">
                                <asp:Button ID="Btn_limp" runat="server" Text="Limpiar" Width="76px" />
                            </td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style23">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="auto-style2">&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:Content>
```

CODIGO DE COMO GUARDO LOS DATOS:

```
Protected Sub Btn_add_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn_add.Click
    conex.Open()

    Dim sqlct As New SqlCommand("insert into dbo.RPT_USUARIO (RUT_USUARIO,DV_USUARIO,NOM_USUARIO,EMAIL_USUARIO,PERFIL_USARIO) values('" & rut.Text & "','" & dv.Text & "','" & nom_usuario.Text & "','" & mail_user.Text & "','" & p_user.Text & "')", conex)
    sqlct.ExecuteNonQuery()

    conex.Close()

End Sub
```

SALUDOS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Y GRACIAS A QUIEN SE ANIME A AYUDARME!!!!!

Comment: Lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score 0):

Tenes varias formas de seleccionar un elemento dentro del DropDownList.
Depdende de que necesites.

```
var item1 = DropDownList2.SelectedItem;
var item2 = DropDownList2.SelectedIndex;
var item3 = DropDownList2.SelectedValue;
```

Comment: ramiro, creo que mi pregunta no está del todo formulada; intentare en esta ocasión expresarme de forma correcta: lo que necesito realizar es que teniendo estas opciones en el dropdownlist: “<asp:ListItem Value="2">Administrador</asp:ListItem>” es que la persona que interactúa con el formulario web, solo ve “Administrador” y cuando lo envíe a guardar a la base de datos se guarde Value="2" y no “Administrador”. Saludos